# How do I unwrap the original Java object that is created with createObject()

Tags: coldfusion

I have a user defined Java object that I'm creating using JavaLoader, which I believe is using createObject() to create the object which is wrapping the original Java object in a ColdFusion Java Proxy Object.  I'm trying to pass this object into another class as an argument but since its wrapped in the proxy I get a type mismatch error.  How can I unwrap this object from the ColdFusion Java proxy?

I'm trying to do is soemthing like this:

```
javaNote = instance.javaObject.createNote(anotherJavaObjectWrappedInJavaProxy);
```

What I have is two Java objects created using createObject and I'd like to pass one of those objects as an argument to another javaObject.

I do have the source for both of the Java files as well so if I can unwrap it in the Java class that would work as well.

Comment: For what purpose, debugging or something else?

Comment: I need to pass this object back into another Java object.

Comment: You should not need to do anything special like "unwrapping". Passing in the object "as is" should work fine as is. Can you post the error message and the code used to create both objects?

Comment: When I pass in "as is" and do a getClass() on the parameter passed into java it is prefixed with object.  For instance If the object is com.idl.MyObject it gets passed in as object.com.idl.MyObject and I get a cast error when trying to cast it like: 

     var MyObject = (MyObject)argumentObject

Comment: Well I do this kind of stuff all the time. But without seeing the error and the create.. code, it is hard to say what is going wrong in your case.

Comment: Also, you do not need to cast except with primitives. Try getting rid of that the "(MyObject") part.

Answer (score 0):

It seems work fine for me. I just tried below code

```
<cfset obj = createObject("java","ResizeImage")>
<cfdump var="#obj#">
```

And it create java object only. See below screenshot.

[image: Output]

Comment: Re: *And it create java object only.* Do not put too much faith in how cfdump formats/displays things. Regardless of what the dump shows, JavaProxy is still used.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getClass()

```html
<cfset obj = createObject("java","java.lang.StringBuilder") />
<cfdump var="#obj.getClass()#">`
```

Comment: Will that just get me the class definition?  I want the actual instantiated object (and its data which is the important part)